# Error in reading and writing file

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I've got a code and there's a problem I don't get it and gives me error :(

```
void write(QString str)
{
    QFile file(str);
    //qDebug()<< file.exists();
    file.open()
    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        qDebug()<<"Error";
        return ;
    }
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "HELLO";

    file.flush();
    file.close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString str = "C:/myText/text.txt";
    write(str);
    //read(str);
    return a.exec();
}
```

It's my funtion in Qt and it prints "Error". Can you guys help me? :)

Comment: Are the two successive calls to `file.open()` on purpose?

Comment: Does the folder `C:/myText/` exist?